# Why this thread doesn't work?

Tags: android, multithreading

I wrote this code to try threads on Android, but it doesn't work.

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override public void run() {
                            int i = 0;
                while(true) {
                                 i += 5;
                                 if(i == 1000000)
                                       break;
                            }
            }
        };
    t.run();
   }
```

I have some GUI and when thread works (i < 1000000), GUI freezes. But when thread is done (i == 1000000) everything works fine. 
What's wrong?

// Sorry for my english

Comment: You could have googled for 5 seconds to see that you're calling the wrong method as explained by @Jon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `t.run()` which means you're running all the code in the UI thread without starting a new thread.

You should call `t.start()` which will instead start a new thread and execute the code in the `run` method within that new thread.

(I'd also recommend implementing `Runnable` and then passing the `Runnable` to a new `Thread` constructor rather than overriding `run`, just as a matter of separation of concerns. It won't change the behaviour here, but it's a cleaner way of thinking about it IMO.)